# How to fetch data from API and then pass it to another component in react after it is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am fetching data from pokeApi and then passing it to another component.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(items =>{
        //console.log(items.results);
        items.results.forEach( item => {
            this.setState({pokemon:[...this.state.pokemon,item.name]})
            this.setState({url:[...this.state.url,item.url]})
 
        })});
}

 
render (){

    return (
        <div>
          
          <Fetchpokemon data={this.state}/>
         
         </div>
        )



}
```

When i console log in Fetchpokemon component, retrievd data is displaying as well as updating.
I want to display data only once.For ex. it should load completely in App.js and then send data to another component.

Comment: It isn't clear how the behaviour you get differs from the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. Add a state variables names loading and show a loader until the data loads. Then we render the components to show the data. I've also simplified the data load logic to call setState only once.

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    // Your initial state
    loading: true,
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(items => {
      const pokemon = [];
      const url = [];
      items.results.forEach(item => {
        pokemon.push(item.name);
        url.push(item.url);
      });
      this.setState({ pokemon, url, loading: false });
     });
}

render (){
  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Fetchpokemon data={this.state}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks!! i was declaring variable arrays but they were local i didnt realized i have to declare them in .then()

Answer (score 0):

Don't call set state so many times, you call it twice for every element of the results array, while you should call it once for the entire thing. Because of it your code is susceptible to asynchronous nature of javascript. You may end up accessing the old version of the state in multiple set statements, adding name of one item to the array, and then removing it while adding another name.

You should perform a single `setState` operation instead of multiple, just reduce your results array to the final state you want and only then update it

```
this.setState(items.results.reduce((newState, item) => {
    return {
        pokemon: [...newState.pokemon, item.name],
        url: [...newState.url, item.url]
    }
}, this.state))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help you.

```js
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
        pokemon: [],
        url: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(items =>{
        //console.log(items.results);
        const names = [], urls = [];
        items.results.forEach(item => {
            names.push(item.name)
            urls.push(item.url)
        });
        this.setState({
            pokemon: [...this.state.pokemon, ...names],
            url: [...this.state.url, ...urls]
        });
    });
}

render () {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                this.state.pokemon.length !== 0 && <Fetchpokemon data={this.state}/>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```